# How to use Apache Nifi to query a REST API?

Tags: apache, rest, bigdata, apache-nifi

For a project i need to develop an ETL process (extract transform load) that reads data from a (legacy) tool that exposes its data on a REST API. This data needs to be stored in amazon S3.

I really like to try this with apache nifi but i honestly have no clue yet how i can connect with the REST API, and where/how i can implement some business logic to 'talk the right protocol' with the source system. For example i like to keep track of what data has been written so far so it can resume loading where it left of.

So far i have been reading the nifi documentation and i'm getting a better insight what the tool provdes/entails. However it's not clear to be how i could implement the task within the nifi architecture.

Hopefully someone can give me some guidance?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 3):

The [InvokeHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html) processor can be used to query a REST API.

Here is a simple flow that

1. Queries the REST API at https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest every 10 minutes
2. Sets the output-file name (`exchangerates_<ID>.json`)
3. Stores the query response in the output file on the local filesystem (under `/tmp/data-out`)

[image]

I exported the flow as a NiFi template and stored it in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/SergiyKolesnikov/61938ac351d46b984522e9346c6e79e8). The template can be [imported into a NiFi instance](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#instantiating-a-template) and run as is.

Comment: How can you handle pagination in the Nifi REST api call that returns next link to get next data page?

Comment: What about Strong Authentication, tokens, etc.?

Comment: @thebluephantom The processor supports multiple authentication methods. See the docs reference.